# Is it possible to have a cell which contains a formula and be able to input text into the same cell?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula, cells

I am trying to create in excel where you enter initials into a cell and the person's full name appears automatically so they do not have to enter their full name every time in a spreadsheet. I have managed to replicate this using nested if statements for different people which works fine but currently it requires two cells and I want to have it on the same cell. I have noticed that if I change the the formula to be in the same cell then it comes up with "circular reference warning" and does not work and if I try to enter text in that cell it replaces the formula. Just wondering is this possible?

```
=IF(C29="HB", "hazel", IF(C29="AO", "amelia", ""))
```

Comment: If you're not had up about it being in the same cell, you could use a vlookup, which feeds off a list of initials maintained in a different table. This would rely on all users having unique initials (then again, any system would), and you would have to maintain the list as new users were added.

Comment: One option is to maintain a list at the top of the column that you enter names in, and hide that list. Then when you start typing names underneath it will fill in the remaining letters as soon as it has a unique match from above. Not quite initials, but still better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Excel's AutoCorrect feature to do this.

Go to File..Options..Proofing -
[image: Options Proofing dialogue]

Click on AutoCorrect Options..

[image]

Enter a pair (or triplet) of initials you want to replace and the name you want the initials to be replaced with, then click add. You can then continue adding Replace With definitions.

It doesn't matter if you enter the Replace in lower case "hb" or upper case "HB" because the entry and its replacement are both added to the definitions in lower case.

Excel does this for a reason - it is sensitive to the case of the cell entry. That is to say if you enter "hb" the autocorrect will change this to "hazel"; if you enter "Hb" you will get "Hazel"; and "HB" will give you "HAZEL".

**The replacement pairs you enter will only apply to the currently logged username.** The replacement pairs will be there every time you open Excel and **are available to all open workbooks.**

If you want the replacement pairs to be available to other users you will need to:

- manually add the replacement pairs to all desired users Excel Options or
- develop a macro to add them using `Application.AutoCorrect.AddReplacement "hb", "hazel"`

If you decide to go down the macro path, you may want to limit the scope of definitions by entering them in certain workbook or worksheet events and consider using the `Application.AutoCorrect.DeleteReplacement "hb"` method.

**Workbook_Open**
The replacements will be available to the current user in all workbooks and will remain until the are deleted manually or programmatically.

**Workbook_Activate and Workbook_Deactivate**
If you use the AddReplacement method in Workbook_Activate and the DeleteReplacement method in Workbook_Deactivate then the replacements will only be available to sheets in the workbook containing the code.

**Worksheet_Activate and Worksheet_Deactivate**
Place the code in a sheet module within the above sheet event handlers and the replacements will only be available in the sheet corresponding to that module.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example that you can adapt to your needs.  The initials input will be in column **A**  so if the user types *JW* in a cell in that column, the cell will change to *James Ravenswood*.

Put the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range
    ary = Array("JW", "VL", "BJM")
    bry = Array("James Ravenswood", "Victor Laszlo", "Bullwinkle J Moose")
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    v = Target.Value
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        If v = ary(i) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Value = bry(i)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

You would need to fill *ary* and *bry* with your initials and names.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**